# Proving convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove whether the following series converge or diverge.

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2(n^2)}$$

I think this series converge and I tried to justify using the ratio test but I got $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ which means the ratio test cannot be applied.

Please give me some ideas or hints on how to solve this question, thanks to anybody who helps.